# Rails uniqueness validator fails on weird double xhr request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, xmlhttprequest, production-environment

I have a form that sends with { remote: true } and an Adopter model that has a uniqueness validator on the email field. Now I have a weird bug in production environment (and I wasn't able to reproduce it in development):

Sometimes if people are creating an Adopter the post request will be sent twice (most of the time everything works fine). When that happens, my Rails app creates two Adopters with the same email. The following is a excerpt from the issue causing requests (I removed boring and private stuff):

```
Started GET "/" for 123.456.789.012 at 2016-06-25 15:03:37 +0000
Processing by LandingController#index as HTML
request http://ipinfo.io/123.456.789.012
{
  "ip": "123.456.789.012",
  "hostname": "12345678.dip0.t-ipconnect.de",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "DE",
  "loc": "1.0000,1.0000",
  "org": "Organistion name"
}
  Rendered landing/index.html.slim within layouts/application (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/application/_head.html.slim (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/application/_ga.html.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 39ms (Views: 6.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/adopters" for 123.456.789.012 at 2016-06-25 15:05:42 +0000
Processing by AdoptersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "name"=>"Mika", "answer"=>{"for"=>"friend", "for_precise"=>"male_friend", "nature"=>"humorous", "interests"=>["technology", "music"]}, "email"=>"nobody@shouldknow.com"}
request http://ipinfo.io/123.456.789.012
{
  "ip": "123.456.789.012",
  "hostname": "12345678.dip0.t-ipconnect.de",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "DE",
  "loc": "1.0000,1.0000",
  "org": "Organistion name"
}
  Adopter Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "97f32b"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "97f32b"]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."sign_up_ip" = $1  [["sign_up_ip", "123.456.789.012/32"]]
  Adopter Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."email" = 'nobody@shouldknow.com' LIMIT 1
  Adopter Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Adopter Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "58b7fd"]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."sign_up_ip" = $1  [["sign_up_ip", "89.15.237.123/32"]]
  Adopter Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE ("adopters"."email" = 'lukas.thorr@web.de' AND "adopters"."id" != 52) LIMIT 1
  Adopter Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE ("adopters"."referral_code" = '97f32b' AND "adopters"."id" != 52) LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE "adopters" SET "referred_count" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "adopters"."id" = $3  [["referred_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 15:05:42.492589"], ["id", 52]]
  SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "adopters" ("name", "email", "gift_for_person", "gift_for_person_nature", "gift_for_person_interests", "sign_up_ip", "referred_by", "locale", "created_at", "updated_at", "referral_code", "referred_count") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Mika"], ["email", "nobody@shouldknow.com"], ["gift_for_person", "male_friend"], ["gift_for_person_nature", "humorous"], ["gift_for_person_interests", "[\"technology\",\"music\"]"], ["sign_up_ip", "123.456.789.012/32"], ["referred_by", 52], ["locale", "de"], ["created_at", "2016-06-25 15:05:42.484886"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 15:05:42.484886"], ["referral_code", "58b7fd"], ["referred_count", 0]]
[ActiveJob]   Adopter Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 54]]
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) with arguments: "AdopterMailer", "signup_email", "deliver_now", gid://Mycoolsite-prelauncher/Adopter/54
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f]   Rendered adopter_mailer/signup_email.html.slim (3.0ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f] 
AdopterMailer#signup_email: processed outbound mail in 8.1ms
Started POST "/adopters" for 123.456.789.012 at 2016-06-25 15:05:44 +0000
Processing by AdoptersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "name"=>"Mika", "answer"=>{"for"=>"friend", "for_precise"=>"male_friend", "nature"=>"humorous", "interests"=>["technology", "music"]}, "email"=>"nobody@shouldknow.com"}
request http://ipinfo.io/123.456.789.012
{
  "ip": "123.456.789.012",
  "hostname": "12345678.dip0.t-ipconnect.de",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "DE",
  "loc": "1.0000,1.0000",
  "org": "Organistion name"
}
  Adopter Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "97f32b"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "97f32b"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."sign_up_ip" = $1  [["sign_up_ip", "123.456.789.012/32"]]
  Adopter Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."email" = 'nobody@shouldknow.com' LIMIT 1
  Adopter Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Adopter Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "860fc4"]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."sign_up_ip" = $1  [["sign_up_ip", "89.15.237.123/32"]]
  Adopter Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE ("adopters"."email" = 'lukas.thorr@web.de' AND "adopters"."id" != 52) LIMIT 1
  Adopter Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "adopters" WHERE ("adopters"."referral_code" = '97f32b' AND "adopters"."id" != 52) LIMIT 1
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f] 
Sent mail to nobody@shouldknow.com (1613.9ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f] Date: Sat, 25 Jun 2016 15:05:42 +0000
From: Mycoolsite <subscribed@mysite.io>
To: nobody@shouldknow.com
Message-ID: <576e9dc67f160_83f98bcce081c5454@1c50fd29020a.mail>
Subject: Mycoolsite - Deine Anmeldung
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
some email content

[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 1625.69ms
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 3f82f6c1-3f4e-4411-a377-2a667d32559f) to Inline(mailers) with arguments: "AdopterMailer", "signup_email", "deliver_now", gid://Mycoolsite-prelauncher/Adopter/54
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (62.8ms)  UPDATE "adopters" SET "referred_count" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "adopters"."id" = $3  [["referred_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 15:05:44.074420"], ["id", 52]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "adopters" ("name", "email", "gift_for_person", "gift_for_person_nature", "gift_for_person_interests", "sign_up_ip", "referred_by", "locale", "created_at", "updated_at", "referral_code", "referred_count") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Mika"], ["email", "nobody@shouldknow.com"], ["gift_for_person", "male_friend"], ["gift_for_person_nature", "humorous"], ["gift_for_person_interests", "[\"technology\",\"music\"]"], ["sign_up_ip", "123.456.789.012/32"], ["referred_by", 52], ["locale", "de"], ["created_at", "2016-06-25 15:05:44.068500"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 15:05:44.068500"], ["referral_code", "860fc4"], ["referred_count", 0]]
Completed 200 OK in 1716ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)
[ActiveJob]   Adopter Load (4.3ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 55]]
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) with arguments: "AdopterMailer", "signup_email", "deliver_now", gid://Mycoolsite-prelauncher/Adopter/55
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60]   Rendered adopter_mailer/signup_email.html.slim (1.7ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60] 
AdopterMailer#signup_email: processed outbound mail in 4.0ms
Started GET "/rank/58b7fd" for 123.456.789.012 at 2016-06-25 15:05:44 +0000
Processing by AdoptersController#refer as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"58b7fd"}
request http://ipinfo.io/123.456.789.012
{
  "ip": "123.456.789.012",
  "hostname": "12345678.dip0.t-ipconnect.de",
  "city": "",
  "region": "",
  "country": "DE",
  "loc": "1.0000,1.0000",
  "org": "Organistion name"
}
  Adopter Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referral_code" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["referral_code", "58b7fd"]]
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "adopters" WHERE "adopters"."referred_by" = $1  [["referred_by", 54]]
   (0.8ms)  
      SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT adopters.id as id, adopters.referred_count as referred_count, row_number() over(order by adopters.referred_count desc) as rn FROM adopters
      ) t where id = 54

  Adopter Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "adopters".* FROM "adopters"  ORDER BY "adopters"."referred_count" DESC, "adopters"."created_at" ASC LIMIT 15
  Rendered adopters/refer.html.slim within layouts/application (7.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/application/_head.html.slim (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/application/_ga.html.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 9.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60] 
Sent mail to nobody@shouldknow.com (1356.5ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60] Date: Sat, 25 Jun 2016 15:05:44 +0000
From: Mycoolsite <subscribed@mysite.io>
To: nobody@shouldknow.com
Message-ID: <576e9dc8265ef_83f98bc2ae3e4546d8@1c50fd29020a.mail>
Subject: Mycoolsite - Deine Anmeldung
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

some email content again

[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 1363.09ms
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: d91eebb4-14ce-43e3-845c-6655c293de60) to Inline(mailers) with arguments: "AdopterMailer", "signup_email", "deliver_now", gid://Mycoolsite-prelauncher/Adopter/55
   (1.1ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 1491ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 72.7ms)
```

This is the Adopter#create action (which is being called twice):

```rb
  def create
    ref_code = cookies[:h_ref]

    @adopter = Adopter.new
    @adopter.name = params[:name]
    @adopter.email = params[:email]
    @adopter.gift_for_person = params[:answer][:for_precise] if !params[:answer][:for_precise].blank?
    @adopter.gift_for_person = params[:answer][:for] if params[:answer][:for_precise].blank?
    @adopter.gift_for_person_nature = params[:answer][:nature]
    @adopter.gift_for_person_interests = params[:answer][:interests].to_json
    @adopter.sign_up_ip = request.remote_ip
    if ref_code && Adopter.find_by(referral_code: ref_code)
      @adopter.referrer = Adopter.find_by(referral_code: ref_code)
    end
    @adopter.locale = I18n.locale

    respond_to do |format|
      if @adopter.save
        cookies[:h_email] = { value: @adopter.email }
        #format.html { redirect_to rank_path(code: @adopter.referral_code) }
        format.js { 
          render :js => "window.location = '#{rank_path(code: @adopter.referral_code)}'"
        }
      else
        logger.info("Error saving user with email, #{@adopter.email}")
        # redirect_to root_path, alert: 'Something went wrong!'

        # format.js {  flash[:notice] = @adopter.errors }
        format.js { flash[:notice] = @adopter.errors }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my Adopter model:

```rb
require 'adopters_helper'

class Adopter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :referrer, class_name: 'Adopter', foreign_key: 'referred_by'
  has_many :referrals, class_name: 'Adopter', foreign_key: 'referred_by'

  validate :not_more_than_two_adopters_per_ip
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: {
    with: /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/i,
    message: 'Invalid email format.'
  }
  validates :referral_code, uniqueness: true
  validates :name, :locale, presence: true, allow_blank: false

  before_create :create_referral_code
  after_create :send_welcome_email
  before_create :compute_queue_positions

  def rank
    row_number_tupel = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
      SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT adopters.id as id, adopters.referred_count as referred_count, row_number() over(order by adopters.referred_count desc) as rn FROM adopters
      ) t where id = #{self.id}
    ")

    row_number_tupel[0]['rn']
  end

  private
    def create_referral_code
      self.referral_code = AdoptersHelper.unused_referral_code
    end

    def not_more_than_two_adopters_per_ip
      if !Rails.env.development?
        adopter_count_with_current_ip = Adopter.where(sign_up_ip: sign_up_ip).count
        if adopter_count_with_current_ip >= 3
          errors.add(:sign_up_ip, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.adopter.attributes.sign_up_ip.max_ips'))
        end
      end
    end

    def send_welcome_email
      AdopterMailer.signup_email(self).deliver_later
    end

    def compute_queue_positions
      self.referred_count = 0

      if !self.referrer.blank?
        self.referrer.update_attributes! referred_count: (self.referrer.referred_count + 1)
      end
    end
end
```

So basically there are two issues. First one, that sometimes the Post request is being sent and processed twice. And second one, that if the first one happens, the uniqueness validator fails.

Comment: Regarding the request being made twice: when you say "in production" do you just mean in the production environment, or is it a live app with users? If the latter, you might want to look into disabling the 'submit' button for that form once it has been clicked - a surprising amount of people still tend to double click on everything.

Comment: It's the latter. I will do that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one: I noticed that users still think they have to double click likes.

Seconds one: No, it does not fail, it is a race condition. Two requests end up at two different instances of the app and both instances check if a similar record already exists, both notice that it does not and therefore both create one. The solution is that you need a unique index on your database to avoid these kind of problems.

Quote from the [Rails Guides about ActiveRecord uniqueness validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness):

> This helper validates that the attribute's value is unique right before the object gets saved. It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database, so it may happen that two different database connections create two records with the same value for a column that you intend to be unique. To avoid that, you must create a unique index on both columns in your database.

Comment: I was guessing this might be the reason. Thought it's probably not cause there are 2 seconds between the both Post requests (first at 42s and sedond at 44s) and that's enough time to write to the database in the first request. I might wrong though.

Comment: If there is a 2s gap it's probably not a double click. However, if the user has still not received any feedback 2s after the click, the action is [very slow in internet terms](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/03/01/technology/impatient-web-users-flee-slow-loading-sites.html). They may be a) unsure that their first click has 'worked' and b) impatient, and so click twice (or more! like mashing an elevator button). As well as disabling the button on click, I would ensure that there is feedback for loading and success (e.g. spinner/popup). Ideally, look into speeding up the action if possible.